# Why do I not see all variables in the debugger?

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am using the debugger for VS Code & in below screenshot, I would expect to see the values for variables, res and nums1. How come they are not listed under 'Closure(intersect)'? (not in the Global submenu either, as I would expect)

[image]

Comment: Probably because they aren’t variables. In the function they’re not shown, maybe because they’re optimized away or because both `res` and `nums1` are identical to the global `nums1` at this point; this isn’t quite clear. However, globally, `nums1` and `nums2` are _not_ variables at all. They’re properties on `globalThis`. See [What is the purpose of the var keyword and when should I use it (or omit it)?](/q/1470488/4642212). Use `const` to make them variables. Also just to note: `let res = nums1;` is unnecessary. Just do `return nums1.filter(`…`);`.

Comment: I suspect it is because the local function (which is the arrow function passed to `filter()`, _not_ the `intersect()` function), doesn't use `nums1` or `res`.

Comment: search way down in the `Global` list, `nums1` is part of the `window` object, `num2` is used in the function so must be included in the Closure

Comment: you have arguments with the name `nums1` and `nums2` and also global vars with these names, use different names to see where they go in the debugger